# JAVA RMI problems on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, server, rmi

I'm trying to run a simple Java RMI on my eclipse, but every time I get different errors. If I run my sources through CMD (I'm on Windows) it works, but I'd prefer to run my code on Eclipse since it's more comfortable!

This is the code:

Interface

```java
package rmiproject;

import java.rmi.*;

public interface HelloIn extends Remote {

    public String ciao(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Server

```java
package rmiproject;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Server extends UnicastRemoteObject implements HelloIn {

    protected Server() throws RemoteException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    public String ciao(String name) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String output= "Server dice ciao "+name;
        return output;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","myipaddress");
        try {
            Naming.rebind("//localhost/Server", new Server());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client

```java
package rmiproject;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class Client {
    private static HelloIn lookup;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            lookup= (HelloIn) Naming.lookup("//localhost/Server");
            String s= lookup.ciao("peppe");
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get if I run it on Eclipse:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public abstract java.lang.String rmiproject.HelloIn.ciao(java.lang.String) throws java.rmi.RemoteException accessible: module Rmi does not "exports rmiproject" to module java.rmi
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:391)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:367)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:315)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:203)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:197)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef$HashToMethod_Maps$1.run(UnicastServerRef.java:598)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef$HashToMethod_Maps$1.run(UnicastServerRef.java:596)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:319)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef$HashToMethod_Maps.computeValue(UnicastServerRef.java:595)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef$HashToMethod_Maps.computeValue(UnicastServerRef.java:574)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.WeakClassHashMap.get(WeakClassHashMap.java:74)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:236)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:473)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:358)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:230)
    at java.rmi/java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.<init>(UnicastRemoteObject.java:212)
    at Rmi/rmiproject.Server.<init>(Server.java:10)
    at Rmi/rmiproject.Server.main(Server.java:29)
```

When I run it on my CMD, these are the steps I follow:

- First I set a path for my JDK and then I start *rmiregistry*.
- Then I open two other windows and I start the server and then the client.

```
javac rmiproject/Server.java
java rmiproject.Server
```

Same for the client on a different window.

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` file in your [Eclipse] Java project? I'm guessing that you do, so add this line to it: `exports rmiproject;`

Comment: @Abra Hi, thank you for your reply! I did this and now I get a new error: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: localhost; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
 at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:625)
 ...

Comment: According to your question, I'm assuming that you are using the default RMI port, i.e. 1099. Either the port is not bound or it is behind a firewall. When you started up _rmiregistry_, you probably got a dialog window asking whether to "allow access" (at least, that's what I got). You need to allow access. By the way, I got the same dialog window the first time I launched your `Server` class. Again, you need to allow access.

Comment: Yep true. I tried this so: I started up rmiregistry from CMD, allowed the acces and now this is what I get: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmiproject.HelloIn
 at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:392)....

Comment: I just fixed it! I solved this last problem just running the rmiregistry from my project path. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You may want to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in this way :

- added exports rmiproject(name of the package) to module-info.java
- start rmiregistry from cmd (in your src path)